# I can't import play-slick dep inside a play project with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to add slick support to a new play project, using slick, and I am faced to a problem : the build.scala is below :

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "sms_play"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
  //other deps
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.5.0.8" 
  )


  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  // Add your own project settings here      
  )

}
```

after having entered this code, I went to my project directory and entered : "play compile"; some files are downloaded but back to eclipse I can't find the libraries in the build path, even after a project refresh.

can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rerun `play eclipse` or `play "eclipse with-source=true"` and refresh the project in eclipse.